# Rendering mathematical symbols in papaja()

Tags: papaja

I'm trying to render what I think should be a very simple table using `kable()` within `papaja()`. One cell in the table includes mathematical symbols, and I get an error message when trying to render the document to pdf.

```
  # some data
  subj <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
  var1 <- c(1, 1, 2, 1, 2)
  var2 <- c("hfg", "hrfg", "thflk", "plht", "sdrpv")
  sum_sq_diffs <- c("Σ√(total))", NA, NA, NA, NA) 

  df <- data.frame(subj, var1, var2, sum_sq_diffs)
```

When I try to render this in `papaja()`, the Σ and √ will not render. I have tried to re-code these using equation notation, e.g. `$sum$ $sqrt$(total)` but I always get error messages:

> ```
>  ! Missing { inserted.
>  <to be read again> 
>               $
> l.129 (Σ √
>                               (total)) & NA & NA & NA...
> ```

I've also tried `$\\sum$ $\\sqrt$(total)` in my code, and have changed the front matter to the following:

```
 latex_engine: xelatex
 header-includes:
 - \usepackage{newunicodechar}
 - \newunicodechar{Σ}{\ensuremath{\sum}}
 - \newunicodechar{√}{\ensuremath{\sqrt}}
```

Note that the equation won't render properly when I view it as a dataframe either (though the original symbols do work in this case), it just shows the string as is specified in the code, with $$s all in place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using LaTeX math directly; the trick here is to use `escape = FALSE` in `kable()` and to ensure that the column names are valid LaTeX expressions (e.g., no `_`). Consider the following example:

```r
 # some data
subj <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
var1 <- c(1, 1, 2, 1, 2)
var2 <- c("hfg", "hrfg", "thflk", "plht", "sdrpv")
sum_sq_diffs <- c("$\\sum\\sqrt\\text{total}$", NA, NA, NA, NA)

data.frame(subj, var1, var2, sum_sq_diffs) |>
  knitr::kable(
    col.names = c("Subject", "Var 1", "Var 2", "Sum of sqaured differences")
    , escape = FALSE
  )
```